# When i am trying to update data in SQLite database it showing an error :

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite for the first time, and trying to learn basic CRUD operation, so I'm facing problem when I am trying to update records. I searched about the solution, In solution they said uninstall the app and try, I tried but I got same error every time. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
The Error I am getting
```

```
19 12:26:26.318 5113-5113/com.example.demointent E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: key_name
2019-08-19 12:26:26.320 5113-5113/com.example.demointent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-08-19 12:26:26.323 5113-5113/com.example.demointent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.demointent, PID: 5113
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: key_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE user_table SET key_name=?,key_phone=?,key_email=? WHERE id=?
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1667)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1615)
        at com.example.demointent.MyDbHandler.updateUserDetails(MyDbHandler.java:96)
        at com.example.demointent.UpdateUserActivity.update(UpdateUserActivity.java:46)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is My DBHelper class

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String key_id = "id";
    private static String key_name = "name";
    private static String key_email = "email";
    private static String key_phone = "phone";

    private static String key_table = "user_table";


    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String create_user = "CREATE TABLE "+key_table+"("+key_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"+key_name+" TEXT ,"+key_email+" TEXT ,"+key_phone+" TEXT "+")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create_user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
public boolean updateUserDetails(UserModel userModel){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("key_name",userModel.getName());
        contentValues.put("key_email",userModel.getEmail());
        contentValues.put("key_phone",userModel.getPhone());

        database.update(key_table,contentValues,"id=?", new String[] {userModel.getId()});
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes from all 3 statements: `contentValues.put(key_name,userModel.getName());`,..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared

```
private static String key_name = "name";
```

Whereas you are trying to update user details by:

```
    contentValues.put("key_name",userModel.getName());
```

The difference here is being "name" and "key_name". To solve this, you should be using column name constants for the CRUD operations.

```
    contentValues.put(key_name,userModel.getName());
    contentValues.put(key_email,userModel.getEmail());
    contentValues.put(key_phone,userModel.getPhone());
```

Comment: @PareshMayani please don't ask people to upvote the answer. It is up to them to do or not to do that.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko haha It's to share information how the Stackoverflow community works and helps each other, and to welcome on-board with helpful information.

Comment: @PareshMayani you know that it is not you who decides if the information is helpful or not, but the community is. Asking to upvote answer ruins natural reputation flow, which could make your answer have higher rating than it is useful. Please let only community decide if it deserves upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Change this lines of code.

```
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("key_name",userModel.getName());
        contentValues.put("key_email",userModel.getEmail());
        contentValues.put("key_phone",userModel.getPhone());
```

To

```
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(key_name ,userModel.getName());
    contentValues.put(key_email,userModel.getEmail());
    contentValues.put(key_phone,userModel.getPhone());
```